# WebService REST Simples

Tags: php, android, web-service, http, rest

Como criar um WebService simples do tipo REST que faça a comunicação HTTP a partir de um dispositivo Android com o servidor, usando a linguagem PHP?

Meu objetivo é fazer *Requests* e receber como resultado uma *Response* do servidor.

Comment: poste a parte do erro do seu código, para nao ser negativado

Comment: Não há erro, pois ainda não implementei, gostaria de saber se existe algo a ser seguido, ou se existe algum Framework que possa me ajudar a fazer essa conexão.

Comment: Você executar um código PHP no Android ou criar um servidor para o Android conectar?

Answer (score 5):

Para `php` eu indico você utilizar um `framework` chamado `PHP Slim Framework`, é muito fácil de utilizar, da uma olhada:

http://tableless.com.br/php-slim-framework/

Exemplo de uso:

```
<?php

require '../Slim/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');

$app->get('/', function () {
echo "SlimProdutos ";
});

$app->get('/categorias','getCategorias');

$app->run();

function getConn()
{
return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=SlimProdutos',
'root',
'',
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);

}

function getCategorias()
{
$stmt = getConn()->query("SELECT * FROM Categorias");
$categorias = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo "{categorias:".json_encode($categorias)."}";
}
```

Acessando `http://localhost/SlimProdutos/categorias`, já tem o retorno esperado.

http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aprenda-a-usar-o-restful-com-php-e-slim-framework