# O que usar para criar site web e app android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, xamarin, xaml

Quero criar um site para hospedar manga ou linkar os mangas de fansub.

Digamos um Mangá Host e criar um app no android para visulizar os mangas sem que precise entrar no site.

Como posso fazer isso?

Desenvolver o site no ASP.NET e depois criar o app na no android?

Encontrei o Xamarin, vi que nele pode desenvolver para cross platform, mas não seria limitado o desenvolvimento?

Algumas pessoas me aconselharam a desenvolver em XAML, porem dizem que é melhor criar algo mais fruído para cada plataforma

Pergunta: Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como te dar o caminho das pedras e dizer: "faça isso, isso e mais isso e você terá tudo o que precisa", até acho estranho a pergunta não ter nenhum voto para ser fechada como *ampla demais* ou *principalmente baseada em opiniões*.

Mas enfim, eu sei bem como é estar numa situação dessas e vou tentar te ajudar de uma forma bem sucinta por aqui, conforme você for desenvolvendo, dúvidas específicas irão surgir e aí poderemos te ajudar melhor.

<sup>**Reforçando:** Vou te dar algumas dicas, não é regra, nem nada.</sup>

> Como posso fazer isso?

Você pensar a frente e começar fazer uma API REST. Fazendo a API que trate o seu modelo de dados, etc. Depois você pode usá-la em qualquer aplicação que estiver desenvolvendo, seja desktop, web ou mobile.

> Desenvolver o site no ASP.NET e depois criar o app na no android?

Isso vai depender do seu gosto, necessidade e outros fatores. Se você for seguir a ideia de criar uma API, eu acho interessante desenvolver a API primeiro. Mas, digo novamente, isso não é regra.

> Encontrei o Xamarin, vi que nele pode desenvolver para cross platform, mas não seria limitado o desenvolvimento?

Limitado de que forma? O Xamarin é muito bom, você desenvolve tudo em C# e da *deploy* num app (praticamente) nativo. Sem contar todas as ferramentas que são disponibilizadas como a [Xamarin Insights](http://xamarin.com/insights) e [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://xamarin.com/test-cloud). Mas claro que isso tudo **é pago**.

Acho que ler essas perguntas vai te ajudar bastante.
[O que é REST e RESTful?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783)
[Diferenças de tipos de Web Service: SOAP, REST, XML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11183/18246)
[WebService REST Simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83151/webservice-rest-simples?s=1|3.3662)